# How to parse an input sentence?

Tags: prolog

I am making a program which takes user input and handles that input based on the user's choice of options. Say I input a string like "hello 4 is a number, and 5 is as well". How can I take the numbers from the string and put them in variables? (In my example I am looking to use the 4 and 5.)

Comment: Parse the individual tokens (atoms) out into a list. You can go through the list recursively to pick off the head each time, `[X|Xs]`. You'll have the atom bound to a variable, say `X`. You can do `number(X)` to determine if `X` represents a number. If you need more fundamental guidance on that, I recommend doing a stackoverflow or google search on "parsing sentences in Prolog".

Answer (score 0):

So, i write some code to solve your problem. First and easyest case: you pass the sentence as a list, like this `[hello,4,is,5,and]`. In this case, you need to check if an element of the list is a number `with number/1`:

```
parseSentence([],[]).
parseSentence([H|T],L):-
    \+(number(H)),
    parseSentence(T,L).
parseSentence([H|T],[H|T1]):-
    number(H),
    parseSentence(T,T1).

?- parseSentence([hello,4,is,5,and],L).
L = [4, 5].
false
```

Second and most interesting case: you pass the sentence as a string, like this: "hello 4 is a number, and 5 is as well". Here the code (a bit redundant to make it more clear):

```
parseSentenceMod([],[]).
parseSentenceMod([H|T],[A|T1]):-
    atom_number(H,A), 
    parseSentenceMod(T,T1).
parseSentenceMod([H|T],L):-
    \+(atom_number(H,_)),
    parseSentenceMod(T,L).

findAtom([],[]).
findAtom([H|T],[H1|T1]):-
    atom_string(H1,H),
    findAtom(T,T1).

parseString(S,P,A,N):-
    split_string(S," ","",P),
    findAtom(P,A),
    parseSentenceMod(A,N).

?- parseString("hello 4 is a number, and 5 is as well",S,A,N).
A = [hello, '4', (is), a, 'number,', and, '5', (is), (as), well],
N = [4, 5],
S = ["hello", "4", "is", "a", "number,", "and", "5", "is", "as", "well"]
false
```

`atom_number/2` checks if the atom is a number, `atom_string/2` creates an atom given a string and `split_string/4` splits the string in substrings separated by, in this case, a blank space. Hope it helps.